# while i execute the above code i get this exception java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.beans.EmployeePm

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

What is the code to retrieve data from the list
while i execute the above code i get this exception  java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.beans.EmployeePm

```
public String showEmpHome(ModelMap map) {
    System.out.println("inside showEmpHome/empHomeController");
    EmployeePm empPm = new EmployeePm();

    int empCode = Integer.parseInt(htSession.getAttribute("empCode").toString());//get empCode from session        

    List<EmployeePm> list = empHomeSer.getEmpHome(empCode);
    System.out.println("List size=" + list.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println("fddfg = "+list.get(i));
        String wrk = list.get(i).getWorkAssigned().toString();
        System.out.println("work = "+wrk);
    }

    map.addAttribute("tabList", list);
    System.out.println("end of showEmpHome/empHomeController");
    return "empHome";
}
```

Comment: The problem is somewhere in `empHomeSer.getEmpHome`. Please provide the code for how you call the query inside.

Comment: @Transactional
    public List getEmpHome(int empCode) {
        System.out.println("inside getEmpHome/empHomeRepo");

        Empmaster empObj = (Empmaster) htSession.getAttribute("emmasterObj");
        System.out.println("empPM" + empObj);
        query = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select e.empmaster,p.pmId,e.empId,p.allotedDate,p.workAssigned,"
                + " p.noOfDays,e.workdone,e.status,e.updatedDate"
                + " from Employee e right join e.pm p");        
        list = query.list();
        return list;
    }

Comment: You can edit the question, but I see the problem. You need to add `EmployeePm.class` as the second parameter in `createQuery`, otherwise it can't know that you want it mapped to that class.

Comment: Looking at your code, another classic mistake you are likely to run into is if you add the parameters using `+`. You must instead use parametrized queries, also known as prepared statements. Please look-up a tutorial on them.

Comment: `List<EmployeePm> list = empHomeSer.getEmpHome(empCode);`  i doubt with this line. Please debug and check here